# Upload metadata as JSON to IPFS

Tags: ipfs, meta-data, pinata

I am uploading NFT-metadata files to the IPFS using Pinata-API and axios:

```
var metadata = {
        "title": "Asset Metadata",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": nameInput.current.value
            },
            "symbol": {
              "type": "string",
              "description": symbolInput.current.value
            },
            "decimals": {
             "type": "integer",
            "description": 0
            },
            "description": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": descriptionInput.current.value
            },
            "image": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "ipfs://"+file.data.IpfsHash
            }
        }
      };
    var metadataUploaded = await axios.post("https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinJSONToIPFS", metadata, 
    {
      headers:{
        'pinata_api_key': "xxx",
        'pinata_secret_api_key': "xxx",
        'path': "metadata.json"
      }
    }).then(function (response) {
      return response;
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

I was expecting the Metadata file would look like a JSON. Calling it from a gateway, it looks like plain text:
[image: Preview of the metadata on a public gateway]

The given path in the header doesnt seem to change anything. Looking into the pinmanager of Pinata, also no name is assigned:

[image: Preview of Pinata, showing that no name was set]

I know that technically it makes little to no difference if it is saved as json or not. But I think you have a better usability and user experience, when youre able to read the metadata formatted. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send them like so:

```
{
    pinataMetadata: {
        name: 'ItemStatus', //i only used this
        keyvalues: {
            // but add_here_if_you_want_more_meta_data
        }
    },
    pinataContent: {
        //put your real JSON object that you want to upload here
    }

}
```

I sent mine like so:

```
const pinataMetadata = {
  name: 'changeFilename-'+ new Date().toLocaleString()
};
nft_json_meta_data = { pinataMetadata: pinataMetadata, pinataContent: nft_json_meta_data };



const resFile = await axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinJSONToIPFS",
    data: nft_json_meta_data,
    headers: {
        'pinata_api_key': environment.PINATA_API_KEY,
        'pinata_secret_api_key': environment.PINATA_API_SECRET,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
});
```